# What will Formatting C:\ do?

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems, formatting

What I am trying to do is just wipe my `C:\` drive and reinstall an operating system.  Is the command the one I want?

Comment: What OS are you going to install on it after you erase it?

Comment: Why would you even need that? Should you use the standard Windows 7 installer, booting from a USB or DVD, there's an option to format your system drive before installation

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/236657/what-will-format-c-do

Answer (score 3):

If you are installing Linux, then you shouldn't need to reformat your hard drive before installing. The same thing applies with Windows.