# what will format c do?

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What will Formatting C:\ do?](https://superuser.com/questions/236653/what-will-formatting-c-do)

What i am trying to do is just wipe my c drive and reinstall an OS is the command the one iwant?

After i wipe the drive i want to install windows 7 64 bit.

I would really like some advice, i am not a computer guy but my friend who is a web developer suggested i try this site if i have questions...

Comment: Formatting the drive will cause you to lose all existing data. It's unclear whether or not this is acceptable to you. If it is, the answers you've received are correct: boot from your Windows 7 DVD and follow the wizard's instructions to format (and repartition) your drive, then install Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Windows 7 disc then just boot from that and follow the instructions, you shouldn't need to wipe/format the drive yourself.

Comment: well i did that already but it put all my old stuff into another file somewhere and i am still showing only 40 gb available on c drive

Comment: You can remove the saved old stuff if you wish...follow instructions here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-remove-the-Windows-old-folder

Answer (score 0):

When you are installing Windows, the installer will wipe and possibly re-format the drive, erasing everything that was there.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your Windows 7 DVD in the DVD-Rom, and restart the computer , it will boot up by itself.
Follow the instructions and from there you can format the drive from a graphical menu .
If the Dvd didn't boot up tell us.

Comment: i tried doing that it said it put my old files in windows.old and my c drive is still bogged down i only have 40 gb available of my 80 gb

Comment: Formating the drive will wipe everything , so have you done it ?

Comment: no but if i do will i be able to reinstall the os?

Comment: No, because format clears everything on the drive including the OS , if you want to reinstall , do not format

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Installing-and-reinstalling-Windows-7